# Problem with writing out large temp files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, temporary-files

I have a set of large image files that I'm using as temporary swap files on Windows in Visual Studio 2010.  I'm writing and reading the files out as necessary.

Problem is, even though each of the files are the same size, I'm getting different file sizes.

So, I can do:

```
template <typename T>
std::string PlaceFileOnDisk(T* inImage, const int& inSize)
    TCHAR lpTempPathBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szTempFileName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwRetVal = GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, lpTempPathBuffer);
    UINT uRetVal = GetTempFileName(lpTempPathBuffer, TEXT("IMAGE"), 0, szTempFileName);

    FILE* fp;
    fopen_s(&fp, szTempFileName, "w+");
    fwrite(inImage, sizeof(T), inSize, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    std::string theRealTempFileName(szTempFileName);

    return theRealTempFileName;

}
```

but that results in files between 53 and 65 mb in size (the image is 4713 * 5908 * sizeof (unsigned short).

I figured that maybe that 'fwrite' might not be stable for large files, so I broke things up into:

```
template <typename T>
std::string PlaceFileOnDisk(T* inImage, const int& inYSize, const int& inXSize)
    TCHAR lpTempPathBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szTempFileName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwRetVal = GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, lpTempPathBuffer);
    UINT uRetVal = GetTempFileName(lpTempPathBuffer, TEXT("IMAGE"), 0, szTempFileName);

    int y;
    FILE* fp;
    for (y = 0; y < inYSize; y++){
        fopen_s(&fp, szTempFileName, "a");
        fwrite(&(inImage[y*inXSize]), sizeof(T), inXSize, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    std::string theRealTempFileName(szTempFileName);

    return theRealTempFileName;
}
```

Same thing: the files that are saved to disk are variable sized, not the expected size.

What's going on?  Why are they not the same?

The read in function:

```
template <typename T>
T* RecoverFileFromDisk(const std::string& inFileName, const int& inSize){

    T* theBuffer = NULL;
    FILE* fp;
    try {
        theBuffer = new T[inYSize*inXSize];
        fopen_s(&fp, inFileName.c_str(), "r");
        fread(theBuffer, sizeof(T), inSize, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    catch(...){
        if (theBuffer != NULL){
            delete [] theBuffer;
            theBuffer = NULL;
        }
    }
    return theBuffer;
}
```

This function may be suffering from similar problems, but I'm not getting that far, because I can't get past the writing function.

I did try to use the read/write information on this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But the suggestions there just didn't work at all, so I went with the file functions with which I'm more familiar.  That's where I got the temp file naming conventions, though.

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to open the image after it's written? It sounds like you're having trouble writing it, too?

You're just asking about why the file sizes are different for the same size picture?  What about how the sizes of the initial files compare to each other?  It may have something to do with the how the initial image files are compressed.

I'm not sure what you're doing with the files, but have you considered a more basic "copy" function?

Comment: There is no compression, these are uncompressed unsigned short images.  I cannot open the image after it's written, and I believe that that is related to the fact that the image files are not the appropriate size.  This is not a copy function, this is using scratch space to avoid memory problems on 32 bit systems.

Comment: Please note, this was not intended as an answer, but merely questions I thought relevant.  Normally I would have put these in a comment but did not yet have enough reputation for that.

Comment: @emragins-- You got distracted into thinking about this problem as an image, rather than just a large file.  As you can see from the code, I'm not compressing the data at all during writeout.  It's also not a copy operation, but a way to avoid memory limitations on 32 bit systems.  The problem has to do with fopen/fwrite/fread/fclose not behaving consistently.

Comment: I was not referring to compression while reading or writing, but rather the way the image file itself is saved which would account for different file sizes even if the images are the exact same dimensions.  That is why I asked about the size of the image files before being loaded into memory.  In any case, I don't claim to know the answer to your problem.  I was merely asking questions I thought would assist somebody else who's more adept at the type of operation you want to do.